# Cannot install tor service

Tags: tor

When I try to install `tor` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package tor has no installation candidate
```

I was able to install it a few days ago, then I had to remove it `sudo apt-get remove --purge tor`

And now I cannot install it.

Any idea why?

Comment: Which release? whats the output of `apt-cache policy tor` ?

Comment: What ubutnu version ?

Answer (score 2):

`tor` is founded in universe repository, so first enable it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Now update software sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install it :

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a force install with `sudo apt-get install -f tor`

If that doesn't work;

Download the package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/tor) and install it with:

`sudo dpkg -i <package_name>`